# How To Disable Arrow Key Navigation For Java Swing JRadioButton?

Tags: java, swing, navigation, jradiobutton, arrow-keys

I have some JRadioButtons in my Java Swing app. After I select one button, clicking on arrow keys will navigate thru all the buttons, but I need to use the arrow keys for other purposes, how to disable the default behavior so pressing on arrow keys won't navigate the radiobuttons ?

```
JRadioButton Button1=new JRadioButton("Button1");
JRadioButton Button2=new JRadioButton("Button2");
JRadioButton Button3=new JRadioButton("Button3");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a `JRadioButton` is added to a `ButtonGroup` "Key Bindings" are added for the left, right, up and down arrow keys:

You can remove the bindings with code like:

```
InputMap im = button1.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "none");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "none");
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more information.

Comment: This worked for me with JTabbedPane after replacing JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT with JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED